# Attach a dompdf file as attachment with PHPMailer without previously saving the file into the disk

Tags: php, dompdf

I want to send an email with an attached pdf file with phpMailer (actually via [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) in wordpress but WP uses phpMailer).

The pdf file is dynamic and I am generating it with [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

**the-pdf-file.php**:

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($HTML);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF
$dompdf->stream();
```

But it's sending the actual php file per se, and not the generated pdf, which is a very logic thing.

I don't know how to force phpMailer to "process" the file before putting it into the mail.

**How I am attaching it**: (Note that wp_mail is a WordPress function that uses PHPMailer)

```
$attachments = array(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/dompdf/generar-pdf.php');
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
wp_mail('...', 'Test - '.uniqid(), 'Whatever', $headers, $attachments);
```

A possible solution would be to save the pdf file into the disk before calling the wp_mail() function, as follows:

```
$output = $dompdf->output();

file_put_contents(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/dompdf/generados/filename.pdf', $output);

$attachments = array(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/dompdf/generados/filename.pdf');
```

And deleting the file afterwards. But I don't know if that is a clean solution to the problem.

Comment: The notes for `wp_mail()` says `The filenames in the $attachments attribute have to be filesystem paths.` so to use this you need to save the PDF to your filesystem first.